# MacOS: Use getxattr/setxattr from a Finder Sync Extension

Tags: macos, finder, appstore-sandbox, entitlements, xattr

I want to use setxattr/getxattr from a Finder Sync Extension on OSX 10.12.6, but the calls fail with errno==1, which is EPERM. Finder sync extensions run in a sandbox, so I guess I need to request permissions. No amount of googling and documentation browsing uncovered information so far.
The files I want to access are owned by myself, and setting attributes with the xattr command line utility succeeds and produces the expected result.

So the question is: Which permissions/entitlements do I need to give the sandbox, or is this possible at all?

I basically want to store the sync status in the extended attributes (clean, modified, syncing) and select the correct badge for requestBadgeIdentifierForURL based on that. A lower priority non-sandboxed process goes over files and updates the attributes.

The alternative would be to use a separate database to store sync status and I'm going to use that if the xattr doesn't work out.

Edit: Added entitlements file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.downloads.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The original entitlements file that comes with the sample is just

```
<key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only</key>
```

which didn't work either.

I added a test project to GitHub https://github.com/JensRestemeier/SyncExtensionTest

Comment: Can you give me a reference/documentation for when/how to use NSOpenPanel for a Finder extension? The Finder Sync Extension is just responding to Finder messages, so I'm not sure if it is safe to open any panels or dialogs.

Comment: (If this comment doesn't make sense, someone suggested that NSOpenPanel would allow to request the permission from the user. That comment was deleted, though I'm still wondering if this is the way to do it...)

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying the path in the entitlement dic.
This is what it should look like:

```
    <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write</key>
    <array>
    <string>/</string>
    </array>
```

This will give you access to all folders on the system.

Comment: I'll have to look at this! Thanks to missing documentation and unpredictable behaviour from sandboxes, especially in future MacOS versions, I had to shelf that project.